# Simplifying ReaderWriterLockSlim Syntax

Tags: .net, multithreading, syntax, simplify, readerwriterlockslim

I recently had to use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to synchronize access to several resources that are shared between multiple threads. While doing it, I felt that using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is not easy specially when you have to use it in multiple places. You have to have `try...finally` blocks and remember to open and close the locks. In many cases I've also found myself opening a write lock and closing a read lock instead of closing the write lock. Therefore I tried to come up with an easier way of using the `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. This is where I got

```
class Locked<T>
{
    private T _resource;
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

    public Locked(T resource)
    {
        _resource = resource;
        _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }

    public void Read(Action<T> ReadAction)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            ReadAction(_resource);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void Write(Action<T> WriteAction)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            WriteAction(_resource);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Now for e.g. if we need to synchronize access to a `List<string>` this is how we do it using the class above

```
public class Demo
{
    private Locked<List<string>> _listOfString;

    public Demo()
    {
        _listOfString = new Locked<List<string>>(new List<string>());
    }

    public void writeMethod(string value)
    {
        _listOfString.Write(list =>
        {
            list.Add(value);
        });
    }

    public string readMethod(int index)
    {
        string value = null;
        _listOfString.Read(list =>
        {
            value = list[index];
        });
        return value;
    }
}
```

Do you think this approach is any better? Are there any shortcomings or flaws.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather wrap the locking logic in an `IDisposable` and put the code you want to lock in a using block, very similar to the `lock` statement:

```
class DisposableLock : IDisposable
{
    Action _exitLock;
    public DisposableLock(Action exitLock)
    {
        _exitLock = exitLock;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _exitLock();
    }
}

class ReadLock : DisposableLock
{
    public ReadLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim slimLock)
        : base(() => slimLock.ExitReadLock())
    {
        slimLock.EnterReadLock();
    }
}

class WriteLock : DisposableLock
{
    public WriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim slimLock)
        : base(() => slimLock.ExitWriteLock())
    {
        slimLock.EnterWriteLock();
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
using(new ReadLock(_lock))
{
    // ... your synchronized operation
}

using(new WriteLock(_lock))
{
    // ... your synchronized operation
}
```

Comment: What advantages does doing this have over the approach I took?

Comment: IMHO it looks cleaner and it looks similar to the lock statement everyone is used to. Additionally, you don't need to change the types of your variables.

Comment: I think it depends on your situation: If you have a lot of lists and the access to each one of them needs to be synchronized, but the lists should be independent, your approach is better, because you directly have one `ReaderWriterLockSlim` per list. In my approach, you would need to have to create an additional `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for each list.

Comment: However, if you have a lot of code that should all be locked by the same lock, my approach is better, because it doesn't restrict you to one type.